# how can i redirect from default controller action to my generated controller action?

Tags: grails, redirect, hyperlink

in my list page of scaffolding i have put a link in span.. on click of that link i want it to take me my own created controller action..

i tried giving `<g:link controller="mycontroller",action="myaction">mylink</g:link>`

that din work for me then i tried

```
<g:link action="redirectingAction">mylink</g:link>
```

but now i am not able to redirect from this `redirectingAction` in default controller which i edited there

what can i do to come out of this problem?

Comment: `<g:link controller="mycontroller",action="myaction">mylink</g:link>` should work, what happens when you click the link and what does the controller action look like (show us the code)?

Comment: put the exact code that you are trying and the error that you are getting...

Comment: Its working now. i had not given , there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `<g:link controller="mycontroller",action="myaction">mylink</g:link>` is wrong. Remove the comma before the action parameter and it should work:

`<g:link controller="mycontroller" action="myaction">mylink</g:link>`

Comment: can u answer to my question on Urlmapping which i have posted today.